# Verb "pigeon hole" in a context

Tags: word-meaning

Provided such a context given by a TOEFL listening text,

> From the perspective of world history, modern history refers to the time around when capitalism began. It is not at all easy, however, to **pigeon-hole** modern Korean history within the world historical context. This is attributed to the historical fact that Korea was colonized by Japan.

I looked up the Merrain Unabridged and Cambridge online,

Merriam Unabridged,

[image]

Cambridge online

[image]

Since to me most suitable definition would be 3 of Merriam, I would like you to confirm if my understanding is correct.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  They are slower to load for users on slow internet connections, difficult to view on small screens, unfriendly to users with vision problems, and do not add anything to the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it means "to put something *where* it belongs (as in a particular compartment or 'pigeonhole' of an old-fashioned desk)" and in this particular context the "where" would be somewhere in a historical *schema* or *analytical framework*.  Ultimately it is a spatial metaphor for something that is not spatial but temporal.

The verb phrase "properly place" could be substituted for it.

Comment: +1 for "properly place". That would make sense too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Merriam definition 3, but with a large side-order of Cambridge definition 1.
The older definition of actual physical boxes to put letters/papers etc in was because they looked like where pigeons would be kept.
We kept the idea of compartmentalising ideas, we kept the name, but we got rid of the physical boxes.

Pigeon-holing [idk whether it really ought to be one word or hyphenated, Brits tend to hyphenate more than anyone else] has distinct connotations of mentally filing things into groups - not necessarily for the benefit of the things/people being filed.

The trouble with that is that the pigeon holes get smaller & smaller until there's only room for one pigeon in each hole ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the nuance of *pigeonhole* is generally *negative* (as in the first Cambridge definition).  It most often means to take something complicated and *force* it to fit some kind of simple role or explanation. Example:

> Early in her career, the actress was lauded for taking on complex roles that required subtle characterization; however as she grew older, because of her maternal appearance, she was quickly **pigeonholed** into those of the doting mother/wife, left wringing her hands at home while her husband or her children went off to fulfill the plot.

The context of your original quote is somewhat less negative, but still a kind of *admonition* against over-simplifying Korean history.  Still it's not exactly clear how being "colonized by Japan" complicates things.